# Disable user interact in a view IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am disabling and enabling a view using the following code....

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

If I do like this, all it subviews also got affected... All are disabled, how do I do only for  particular view? Is it possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's exactly the same, assuming your other view is either a member or you can iterate through `self.view`'s array of subviews, like so:

**MyViewController.h**

```
UIView* otherView;
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
otherView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // or YES, as you desire.
```

OR:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[self.view subviews] count]; i++)
{
    UIView* view = [[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex: i];

    // now either check the tag property of view or however else you know
    // it's the one you want, and then change the userInteractionEnabled property.
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In swift `UIView` do have property `userInteractionEnabled` to make it responsive or not. To make full View unresponsive use code:

```
// make screen unresponsive
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
//make navigation bar unresponsive
self.navigationController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

// make screen responsive
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
//make navigation bar responsive
self.navigationController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: How about if use this elf.view.userInteractionEnabled = false but i wanan enable only a button?

Comment: self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false will stop your application UI to respond to any touch (As per the question asked). If you want to make just one button enable then you should not use this code. You can somehow disable individual UIView elements to stop responding to touch.

Comment: Oh i see , thats why i have asked if theres a way to disable all except for one

Comment: The property has been renamed to `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[/*"which ever class u want eg UITextField "*/ class]])

        [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use `Tag` property of the view rather than iterating all its subviews. Just set tag to the subView which you want to disable interaction and use below code to access it and disable interaction.

```
// considering 5000 is tag value set for subView 
// for which we want to disable user interaction  
UIView *subView = [self.view viewWithTag:5000]; 
[subView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, however I have multiple views so I needed to hide them all. Another thing that I did was make a view with a background so that it grayed out the view I was disabling.